# Is there a polling or voting application for Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook-groups

That's it ... I have a secret Facebook group and I frequently need people to vote on things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the group has a wall, you should be able to post a "Question" to it (a new feature rolled out a few days ago).

[image: A close screen shot of the new Question option for Facebook wall posts.]

Comment: Yes but this has an limitation of only 10 options :(